# Multiple backgrounds like with CSS3 in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, gradient, css

How can I create the same effect with Illustrator as with following CSS:

```
background: linear-gradient(#5d7aa4, transparent) fixed,
            linear-gradient(-45deg, #ff0068, transparent) fixed, 
            linear-gradient(45deg, #00ecff, transparent) fixed;

background-blend-mode: multiply;
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/eycspbt9/

I tried to create 3 overlapping elements with same gradient, opacity and blend mode settings, but it doesn't look same. What am I missing?

Comment: Adding a screenshot of your attempt in Illustrator would help

Answer (score 3):

Simple Blue to Blue linear Gradient....

[image]

Add a new fill via the **Appearance Panel** and set the new fill to be the purple gradient 100% to Transparent...

[image]

Then to adjust the angle of the purple gradient, grab the **Gradient Tool** and click-drag from the bottom right corner upwards....

[image]

Or just enter "135" in the angle field for the gradient (matches the 45°/-45° "to top" gradient angle in CSS.. but not necessarily the gradient *length*)....

[image]

That should get you close...

[image]

Adjust further as desired.

Chances of you *exactly* matching CSS blend modes and settings in *any* image editing application are somewhat minimal. CSS does it's own browser-specific translations. In addition, coordinates are always window or parent object specific with CSS, so gradient lengths can easily change in CSS (*this is the biggest difference*). This also can result in angles appearing different even if they are still set to the same degree.